# What is the meaning of exit code -100 from sqlcmd

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio-2012, sqlcmd

I have a C# console app, which call sqlcmd utiltiy, and get the exit code as -100.

Code looks like below;

```
    private int RunSP()
    {
        int exitCode = 1;

        Log.Log("Creating Stored Procedure: " + Config.ExternalSPname);
        Process p = new Process();

        // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        p.StartInfo.FileName = string.Format("sqlcmd -S {0} -d {1} -Q \"EXIT(exec {2} @ MainListID=N'{3}', @ TempListID =N'{4}')\"", Config.ExternalSPserver, Config.ExternalSPdb, Config.ExternalSPname, Config.ExternalSPmainlist, Config.ExternalSPtemplist);
        Log.Log("SP command: " + p.StartInfo.FileName);

        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
        exitCode = p.ExitCode;
        p.Close();

        return exitCode;
    }
```

The stored procedure is written as return exit code 1 when it's worked, 0 when it's failed.

I wonder if sqlmod can return -100 in certain cases.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check if FileName is getting proper value/

Comment: You may need to the the `-b` and/or `-V` options to `sqlcmd` to get a meaningful ERRORCODE result.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Comment: @Narendra FileName seems ok

Comment: @MichaelBurr I'm testing using your recommendation. For now, the issue seems just on the blank between @ and MainListID and another blank between @ and TempListID.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBurr, the meaing of -100 from sqlcmd was on the link you commented.